# Switch to nowhere

Tags: switch

I have a dimmer switch with black,white,ground only coming in, looks like direct from the panel, not coming from another switch/power source.
However, there are no wires going out, not sure why the previous owner did this.
I want to replace it with just a rocker switch. What do I do with the wires?  Attach to switch? what would i do with neutral?  Just cap everything before it reaches the switch?
Thanks.

Comment: Does the dimmer switch do anything? That is, is it controlling something?

Comment: If it doesn't control anything, why would you replace it with a toggle/rocker switch? Use a blank plate and cap/nut the wire separated. If it's controlling something, it is most likely that the power goes to the device and the switch is after it therefore no need for multiple wires. It still completes a circuit.

Comment: the switch does not control anything. i was putting in the rocker switch for pure aesthetics.  its part of a 3 gang box with two other switches that actually control lights.  right now i just capped each wire separately.

Comment: Have you checked all the plugs in the room - both top and bottom?  It could be for a switched outlet, and the previous owner could have replaced a switch with a dimmer to make a dimmable floor lamp.

Comment: @Drew This sounds suspicious to me - Marks comment is probably accurate- easier for DIY'er to run the 3 wire somewhere black for hot [IN], white is his [out] and the ground. It operates something. Measure your voltage between GND and the two other wires. If you have voltage in - it feeds something. If you cap wires off and add a switch for 'aesthetics'  you might find an outlet not working or an outdoor something not working. If your selling the home - just wall plate it. A dead switch might be discovered.

Comment: There may also have been a fan/light with separate switches.   If that was a dimmer to a receptacle, that is illegal.  You vannot dim a receptacle unless it is specially keyed to take a lamp only.

Comment: Have you tested this switch with a voltage meter?

Comment: I have a couple of those in my house, it just happens sometimes, I can't remember what I was going to do with them.

Comment: How is the dimmer currently wired? Are there wires on both the line and load terminals?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a black, white and green connected to any switch it is not coming from the panel. That would be a direct short to the breaker when you turn it on. My best guess is that the black and white wires are a switch leg to somewhere or it might be a set of carriers to a three way switch. Yes they do make three way dimmers.

As a matter of safety if you do not want to keep the dimmer. You need to wire nut the wires off individually. Worst case scenario, you find a light or switch receptacle that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found it with a voltage meter.
There is a junction box in the floor that is covered with a rug with the wires taped off inside. 
I set the switch to the off position and will leave it at that.

Comment: Since you don't know what the switch was intended to do, and this answer isn't particularly useful to the community, please consider deleting your question.

Comment: @isherwood -- do you mean deleting his *answer*?

Comment: No. The details of the question are sketchy to begin with. I see little value in the whole shebang.